# SVG shapes is jagged even with antialiasing turned on

Tags: html, vector, svg

I have an svg image of two polygons in 220x220px container but I wonder if I can make the edges antialiased better?

http://jsfiddle.net/swist666/1Lk692xb/

```
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" id="ob" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" enable-background="new 0 0 595.3 841.9" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="LOGO">
    <polygon points="311,374.7 417.7,401.7 565.4,380.8 438.6,342.4  "/>
    <polygon points="298.4,370 426.9,337.5 298.4,298.5 169.9,337.5  "/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

I have beed playing around with shape-rendering and that was not what I'm looking for.

Comment: 220 pixels is a pretty small area. Other than buying an iMac with Retina display, I think you're out of luck

Comment: You have a high contrast edge on a shallow angle.  You are not really going to get any better than that.